# Android Application is crashing in debug mode working fine in release mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, material-components-android

**Description**: I didn't make any changes to my code.

This issue is reproducing for both 4.1.1 and 4.4.0 Gradle versions

App crashing in debug mode but working fine in Release mode.

I tried reinstalling the android studio Nothing helps me

**Android API version:** Android API version Android 11 (30 )

**Material Library version:** com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1

**Device:** Pixel 3a

Reproducing for all Material components Bottom sheet dialog, Bottom navigation view

https://www.loom.com/share/e2347984737d4988b257a584ada13acb

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1877

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
 at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog.wrapInBottomSheet(BottomSheetDialog.java:216)
 at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog.setContentView(BottomSheetDialog.java:93)
 at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:504)
 at com.rizek.android.users.views.bottomsheet.ExpandedBottomSheetFragment.onActivityCreated(ExpandedBottomSheetFragment.kt:28)
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2718)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:346)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1200)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
 at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2181)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2004)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1959)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1861)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2641)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2589)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1435)
 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8024)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3475)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)


 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.rizek.android.users.test:layout/activity_dashboard: Binary XML file line #38 in com.rizek.android.users.test:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.rizek.android.users.test:layout/activity_dashboard: Binary XML file line #38 in com.rizek.android.users.test:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38 in com.rizek.android.users.test:layout/activity_dashboard: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696) at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170) at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303) at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284) at com.rizek.android.users.base.BaseActivity.performDataBinding(BaseActivity.kt:370) at com.rizek.android.users.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:223) at com.rizek.android.users.ui.dashboard.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.kt:79) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 2020-11-18 13:36:59.578 7372-7372/com.rizek.android.users.test E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setImportantForAccessibility(int)' on a null object reference at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setImportantForAccessibility(ViewCompat.java:1119) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:104) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:87) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationItemView.<init>(BottomNavigationItemView.java:83) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.getNewItem(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:606) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.buildMenuView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:538) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationPresenter.updateMenuView(BottomNavigationPresenter.java:67) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:344) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:226) at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:133) ... 34 more
```

Comment: can you post the crash log ?

Comment: This might have something to do with the Theme you are using try posting a  http://sscce.org/ i vaguely remember having this issue and I think it has something to do with using or not using Theme.AppCompat

Comment: Whats your current theme in styles.xml? have you tried Theme.MaterialComponents?

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat Added the crash logs

Comment: @DavidKroukamp My Theme Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar.Bridge

Comment: Please post your xml layout and activity code where crash occurs

Comment: @SarahKhan It was working fine in release mode 

This issue is intermittent